# WinRT Derive Shape

Tags: c#, inheritance, windows-runtime, shapes

I was going to derive the Shape class to create a custom reusable shape, everything seemed ok up until.

> **NotImplementedException: Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Shape.get_GeometryTransform()**

It is not clear whether or not third party developers of the WinRT platform were intended to inherit this class.  Not only am I unable to override that particular property (it must have the internal access modifier specified) there also seems to be no way to pass the custom geometry to the rendering system.

This isn't the only class I have come across with similar problems, (i.e. seems like you can inherit it for your own custom controls, turns out you can't) the Selector class is one such example.

Very frustrating.

Does anyone know what the intentions were, in terms of deriving the Shape class and what workaround should I employ if any? I wouldn't really want to go too far down the hierarchy lest I provide redundant properties in my custom Shape.

Cheers

Comment: You can't derive from a `Shape` in C# currently. There's something wrong with the projection. You might be able to in C++ if you wanted to try.